# Validation Error: Error #-26: 258: txn-mempool-conflict. Action required?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I am getting this error message when trying to send from my blockchain.info wallet.  "Validation Error: Error #-26: 258: txn-mempool-conflict"  Will this eventually be resolved automatically or is action required on my part to be able to send again from my wallet?

Comment: why not to ask blockchain.info support?

Comment: ok, i'll try that.  Last time I contacted blochain.info support it took a long time to get a response.  I was looking for a simple answer, if anybody knew, but thank you.

Comment: Same experience. Haven't heard back from them in 20 hours.

Comment: Same error. It's been a week since I contacted blockchain.info support. They replied, and asked for my extended private key but still haven't solved my issue.